# Flutter Expansion Panel

Tags: flutter

Any ideas on how to go about styling flutter's Expansion Panels and/or Expansion Panel Lists? By default it uses the theme's `cardColor` attribute for the background. I would like to change things like the border and elevation.
Thanks

Comment: Would be easy to do that if `_ExpansionPanelListState` was not private. I think the best option you got right now is copying the whole `expansion_panel.dart` and pasting it in your project, then you can wrap `_ExpansionPanelListState`'s `build` in a widget that contains your custom style. You can also make a PR or open a issue asking Flutter team to make `_ExpansionPanelListState` public or protected.